# Can someone help me figure out why i cant call my method?

Tags: java, methods

I can't figure out why I can't call my method. I checked it over a few times and tried running it, but it always ends right after I enter a value for the money. It's supposed to return the amount of change for a given amount of money, using hundred, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, singles, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. So if it was $42.55, the output would be "0 0 2 0 0 2 2 0 1 0" (two twenties, two singles, two quarters, one nickel). Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MakeChange {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Scanner readmoney = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Money amount? >");
    double money = readmoney.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    String thing = makeChange(money);
}

public static String makeChange(double money) {

    int hundreds = (int) money/100;

    int fifties = (int)(money/50) - (2*hundreds);

    int twenties = (int) (money/20) - (5*hundreds) - (int)(2.5*fifties);

    int tens = (int)(money/10) - (10*hundreds) - (5*fifties) - (2*twenties);

    int fives = (int)(money/5) - (20*hundreds) - (10*fifties) - (4*twenties) - (2*tens);

    int singles = (int)(money) - (100*hundreds) - (50*fifties) - (20*twenties) - (10*tens) - (5*fives);

    int quarters = (int)(money/0.25) - (400*hundreds) - (200*fifties) - (80*twenties) - (40*tens) - (20*fives) - (4*singles);

    int dimes = (int)(money/0.1) - (1000*hundreds) - (500*fifties) - (200*twenties) - (100*tens) - (50*fives) - (10*singles) - (int)(2.5*quarters);

    int nickels = (int)(money/0.05) - (2000*hundreds) - (1000*fifties) - (400*twenties) - (200*tens) - (100*fives) - (20*singles) - (5*quarters) - (2*dimes);

    int pennies = (int)(money/0.01) - (10000*hundreds) - (5000*fifties) - (2000*twenties) - (1000*tens) - (500*fives) - (100*singles) - (25*quarters) - (10*dimes) - (5*nickels);

    String change = (hundreds + " " + fifties + " " + twenties + " " + tens + " " + fives + " " + singles + " " + quarters + " " + dimes + " " + nickels + " " + pennies);

    return change;
```

}
}

Comment: What do you want to do with `thing`? Perhaps you want to `System.out.println(thing)` to print it to the console?

Comment: Looks like it's doing exactly what you told it to...

Answer (score 4):

```
 String thing = makeChange(money);
}
// end of program
```

You're not printing your result.

The method gets called (and does not crash with an exception).

Answer (score 0):

The method gets called successfully. It returns a result, stores it in the variable, and then the program ends. You need to actually print the return value to the console in order to show something.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Scanner readmoney = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Money amount? >");
    double money = readmoney.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();

    String thing = makeChange(money);
    System.out.println(thing);
}
```